# Pass a dictionary as default arguments of a function

Tags: python, arguments, parameter-passing

let's say i have a function like this:

```
def foo (a = "a", b="b", c="c", **kwargs):
    #do some work
```

I want to pass a `dict` like this to the function as the only argument.

```
arg_dict = {
    "a": "some string"
    "c": "some other string"
}
```

which should change the values of the `a` and `c` arguments but `b` still remains the default value.

since `foo` is in an external library i don't want to change the function itself.

is there any way to achieve this?

**EDIT**

to clarify `foo` has both default arguments like `a` and has `keyword arguments` like `**kwargs`

when i do this:

```
foo(**arg_dict)
```

`**arg_dict` is passed as the `**kwargs` and other arguments stay the default value.

Comment: You mean `foo(**arg_dict)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpack the `arg_dict` using `**` operator.

```
>>> def foo (a = "a", b="b", c="c", **kwargs):
...     print(f"{a=}")
...     print(f"{b=}")
...     print(f"{c=}")
...     print(f"{kwargs=}")
... 
>>> arg_dict = {
...     "a": "some string",
...     "c": "some other string",
...     "addional_kwrag1": 1
... }
>>> 
>>> foo(**arg_dict)
a='some string'
b='b'
c='some other string'
kwargs={'addional_kwrag1': 1}
```

Comment: when i do this ```**arg_dict``` is passed as the ```**kwargs``` and other arguments stay the default value.

Comment: @Anthraxff I don't quite understand your statement. My answer is tested in python 3.11. As you can see `foo` prints correct `a`, `b`, `c` values.

Comment: yeah i tested and it works outside of the external library it seems that some other stuff i going on. I'm gonna accept the answer though. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This works out of the box like

```
foo(**arg_dict)
```